# How can I export itunes playlists for use with other media players?

Tags: itunes, mediamonkey

The *export playlist* feature gives a text file that doesn't seem easily importable. Ideally it would export as an m3u or something similar.

So, how can I export iTunes playlists for use with other media players?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't miss something? Seems iTunes has had the ability to [export playlists in M3U format](http://www.ehow.com/how_8302731_export-itunes-m3u.html) for some time now:

[image: 1]

Just in case that doesn't work for some reason, there are always third party apps such as [iTunes Export](http://www.ericdaugherty.com/dev/itunesexport/) or [iExporter](http://iexporter.codeplex.com).

Comment: The instructions on the linked page are somewhat unnecessary. You can just right click on the playlist and select "Export". Bam.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Thanks for the info. I wouldn't touch iTunes with a barge-pole personally, but I'm sure the OP will be happy to know. :)

Comment: thank you so much... i don't know why i assumed that just because it was defaulting to text file output meant that was the only option :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about exporting playlists out of iTunes, but Winamp can pull them into a format you can either keep in Winamp, or pull out as an M3U.  It has the ability to import iTunes playlists from a fresh install, where it should ask you to import your existing iTunes library & playlists.  It also has the ability to import both from the library menu, should you already have Winamp installed.

Here's a great write-up with instructions from January 2013:

http://www.wondershare.com/apple-software/import-itunes-library-to-winamp.html

Answer (score 1):

If interested, I created a utility (freeware) that exports iTunes playlists to .m3u playlists and can transform the paths on the fly for use by, say, SONOS import or WMP or VLC.   See http://www.simav8.com/itunesxmltom3u.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this github Project:

Link: http://itunes2m3u.esy.es/

Github: https://github.com/mohitk117/iTunes-Playlist-Converter

> **iTunes-to-M3U-Playlists**
>
> A webapp that lets you convert Itunes Library.xml playlists to m3u
>   playlists.
>
> How to Convert to m3u
>
> - Enable XML File for your Itunes Library in Itunes Settings.
> - Browse for your Itunes Library xml File.
> - Once selected the page will automatically load all the playlists from your Library file.
> - To select a playlist/folder, check the playlist/folder checkbox.
> - Select all the playlists required for download in .m3u format, and click on download.
> - Playlists will then be downloaded in a zip format.
> - Tested with iTunes v12 or 2014+ to latest version 2016

Opens locally in browser, and no installation required!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Both links are broken

Comment: I'll try and upload it to github... Don't have it hosted these days